# A categorical regressor with many categories: my linear regression coefficients do not make sense

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, many-categories

Model:

```r
multiple.regression <- lm(Pocket.Price ~ Pocket.Margin + SKU  + 
                          Sold.To.Customer + Quantity, 
                          data = new_data3)
```

I have a data set with SKU, Buyer, Quantity, Date, Selling Margin, Selling Price. I am trying to use this data to establish a base SKU pricing list. The goal is that the base SKU price could then use the coefficient of Buyer, Quantity, etc to ballpark the final price.

[image: Data Summary]

I have ran a linear regression model. I used this to remove several additional columns that were redundant.

[image: Coefficients]

Everything looked fine until I compared the coefficient to a handful of old base pricing for a sanity check. Everything in Blue is a SKU.

[image: Coefficients vs old pricing]

I think there is a problem with my model fit. I tried to follow this https://bio723-class.github.io/Bio723-book/fitting-regression-models-in-r.html but I think because my SKU is a factor it messed it up.
[image: Fitted data]

[image: Fit coefficients]

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this or what step I am missing. Please advise!

Comment: What is the model?  So much is redacted that it's impossible to determine what you're doing.  One thing is clear: using a predictor with 804 levels to fit only 3709 observations is unlikely to be any good.

Comment: multiple.regression<-lm(Pocket.Price ~ Pocket.Margin+SKU  +Sold.To.Customer+ Quantity, data = new_data3)

Comment: That's even worse, because there are even more variables.

Comment: TRy some form of regularization, serach this site for lasso ...